# Lyric of Final Fantasy XV - Apocalypsis Noctis

Tags: lyrics, meaning, videogame-soundtrack

I'm not good at Latin but I found one of Final Fantasy XV interesting.
It was played live in Abbey Road Studios few days ago.

I would like to know if anyone could write down the lyrics also with meaning if possible, but lyrics itself is already more than enough for me.

Here the link on YouTube:

[Orchestra Live at Abbey Road Studios (Official)]
https://youtu.be/T0dabzg9GbM?t=51m47s

[More Clearer Voice]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmIjrjHEYSc

Answer (score 2):

I found this one video that shows the "supposed" lyrics. I'm not sure how accurate it is, but the video seems to suggest that they're actually singing in Turkish, funny as that sounds.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_pVP65mgNQ (This is the video)

Plugging some stuff into Google Translate (yeah I know I know hate on me for it) I get this for about the first bit -

wall
Get up
Ahmet
mom
office
Ahmet sit
Elnur
Neither stop nor get up
Office is our
Neither stop nor get up
Ahmet sende
still same
What color sausage
Office is here
Everything beer
what is that
Our lonely nights

Nolur idris
It chips a bit
Give me less
Bring alone
Record income mehmet'e

Some parts just don't make sense. Other parts do. Here's what the supposed lyrics in Turkish were -

duvar 
kalk dur 
ahmet 
anne 
ofis 
ahmet otur
elnur sabri içiş elyas
ne dur ne kalk
ofis bizim
ne dur ne kalk
ahmet sende
hala aynı
ne renk sosis
ofis burda
her şey bira
o ney
yalnız gecelerimiz

nolur idris
o cips biraz
bana da versene az
getir yanlız
rekor gelir mehmet'e

I'm not sure if that helped, but either way it's interesting.

Comment: I looked up something else - Ahmet is actually a Turkish given name - it's derived from a Turkish word meaning "To thank or praise." I guess that might help???

Comment: These are just jokes as misheard lyrics, not the real lyrics.

Comment: I believe the lyric come from latin language, however nice catch!

Answer (score -2):

**LatinEdit**

- Deus dormit

  Et liberi ignem faciunt

  Numquam extinguunt

  Ne expergisci possit

  Omnia dividit

  Tragedia coram

  Amandum quae

  Et nocte perpetua

  In desperatione

  Auroram videre potest

  Mane tempus expergiscendi.

**English translation**

- God sleeps

  And children are able to light a flame

  They never extinguish

  But he will never awake

  Separate everything,

  This tragedy destroys,

  every beloved thing.

  And in this endless night,

  In despair

  He may see the dawn

  That will awake him in the next morning

Comment: This is not the right answer
The Lyric that you provided is for "Somnus" song, what I asked for is "Apocalypsis Noctis"

Please check the YouTube links that I provided